# Vue.js - access parent property in child render function with JSX syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scope, render

I have two components

Parent: `AjaxLoader.vue`

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'AjaxLoader',
        props: {
            url: {},
        },
        render() {
            return this.$scopedSlots.default({
                result: `resultData of ${this.url}`,
            });
        },
    };
</script>
```

Child: `SearchInput.vue`

```
<template>
    <AjaxLoader url="/api/fetch/some/data">
        <template slot-scope="{ result }">
            <div>{{ result }}</div>
        </template>
    </AjaxLoader>
</template>
```

Now I can pass variable from parent to child and in child component can display parent `result` variable. In this case in result var should be `resultData of /api/fetch/some/data`.

My question is: **How can I write this logic of child component into render function with JSX syntax ?**

I tried:

```
<script type="text/jsx">
    import AjaxLoader from './../ajax-loader/AjaxLoader.vue';

    export default {
        components: { AjaxLoader },
        name: 'SearchInput',
        render(h) {
            return (
                <AjaxLoader url="/api/fetch/some/data">
                    <template slot-scope="{ result }">
                        <div> {{ result }} </div>
                    </template>
                </AjaxLoader>
            );
        },
    };
</script>
```

But I got error: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: result is not defined"`

I already have installed plugins for JSX support of Vue.js

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for child component. Maybe it someone helps.

```
render(h) {
    return (
        <AjaxLoader url="/api/fetch/some/data">
            {(props) => <div> {props.result} </div>}
        </AjaxLoader>
    );
},
```